# How to change cell reference in all formulas on a work sheet

Tags: excel, reference, offset, vba

I am a beginner in VBA so I hope this isn't a stupid question. I searched around and can't find a simple way to do what I need.  So I have a data sheet that feeds 12 other worksheets (1 for each month) and I need to offset the cell references in all formulas on the sheet 13 rows down.  For example:

I need my formula to change from "=Data!C18" to "=Data!C31"

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Misunderstood your question the first time. Here's what you can do:

If your formulas are simple references as you give above, then this general approach should work:

```
Sub shift_reference(rgRange As Excel.Range, iRowOffset As Integer)

  Dim rgCell As Excel.Range
  Dim sFormula$, iRow%

  For Each rgCell In rgRange.Cells

    ' read formula from cell
    sFormula = rgCell.FormulaR1C1

    ' cut off = sign from equation
    sFormula = Right$( sFormula, Len( sFormula ) - 1 )

    ' insert offset command and reassemble
    sFormula = "= offset( " + sFormula + ", " + CStr( iRowOffset ) + ", 0 )"

    ' set new formula for this cell
    rgCell.FormulaR1C1 = sFormula  

  Next rgCell
End Sub
```

The difficult part of course is the commented one - if all your formulas are just references as given above, then this shouldn't be hard, just a bit tedious (you'll need to extract row and column number from the formula with string-manipulation). Do you need any help with that?

UPDATE:
Ok, you can also simply insert the `offset` command that's available in  Excel. That gives you further options: Right now, I've used a "hard coded" row offset - the one that's passed as argument. Alternatively, you can also use a cell reference, in which you enter the ror offset - if it ever should change, you simply have to update one argument. Let's say, the cell containing the offset is A1, then the insert-line in the code becomes

```
sFormula = "= offset( " + sFormula + ", A1, 0 )"
```

And last, but not least, nothing prevents you from also inserting *column* offsets, too, in which case you need to replace that third argument of the offset formula (currently containing `0`) with whatever your heart desires.

Let me point out at this point, that I'm not sitting at any Windows machine right now, so I'm dry-coding, but this should be fairly ok.

Comment: Thanks for the help Rob! The problem is all the formulas reference different cells.  I have to update 50 different cell references on all 12 sheets, with each sheet needing to move all the references down 13 rows more than the sheet before.

Comment: Awesome!  Yea, I need a bit of help. one example and I should be able to get the rest myself.  Thanks again.

Comment: Hi @tedi, I've updated the example. Hope it works - I can't test it right now.